# State the domain of each composite function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

So we started a new section in precal today and I'm still trying to get the hang of it. I have a problem asking for:

> For the given functions $f$ and $g$ find:
>
> (a) $f\circ{g}$
> (b) $g\circ{f}$
> (c) $f\circ{f}$
> (d) $g\circ{g}$
>
> $f(x)= x + 1$ and $g(x)=x^2 - 4$

Would the domains be the following?
(a) $g(g(1))=\mathbb{R}$
(b) $f(f(1))=\mathbb{R}$
(c) $f(f(1))=\mathbb{R}$
(d) $g(g(1))=\mathbb{R}$

I highly doubt that's right. :/

Comment: The title of the question and the body are different. Do you want to know the domains of the functions, or do you want to know what the actual functions are?

Answer (score 0):

a) $f\circ{g}=x^2-3$

b)  $g\circ{f}=(x+1)^2-4$

c) $f\circ{f}=x+2$

d)  $g\circ{g}=(x^2-4)^2-4$

The second part doenst make sense because they are not functions, but numbers!

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above, there is contradictory information about what question Vernard actually wanted to ask - in the title, he asking about the domains of the functions (which of course are sets), but that is not what the actual question he referenced asks about.

Comment: yes, but you wrote it when I was writing the answer so I couldn't see before posting it!